# Help decide between Fuse or Kernel module for exFAT filesystem

Tags: 18.04, filesystem, exfat, fuse

I have a program that writes encoded video into external storage with moderate bandwidth. I find that exFAT is a good filesystem for such storage since it enables linux/mac/windows platforms; therefore, I would like to stick to using it.
Nevertheless, I found some issues regarding stability when devices are full, using fuse drivers. I can not pinpoint such problems with 100% guarantees since they are rather erratic.

I have seen benchmarks of the kernel driver which are stunning, and I have read about the Samsung driver leak. Other than that I can not find much literature to help me decide.

therefore the question is:

- What are the reasons that motivated the migration of fuse to kernel module exFAT driver between ubuntu 18 and 20?
- Where there missing features or stability issues with the fuse version?

I would appreciate any link or literature about the rationale, which could help me understand and decide since I am working with ubuntu 18 for the time being and I would have to provide the kernel driver manually.

Answer (score 1):

> I would appreciate any link or literature about the rationale,

If you find, please let us know.

File system drivers that are mature are adopted in the kernel - of the license permits. This ensures maximum performance and stability: the kernel is what talks directly to the hardware. A driver in user space can be seen as a go between between the operating system and the hardware. If the go-between can be bypassed, there direct communication.

> Help decide between Fuse or Kernel module

If you choose to stay with Ubuntu 18.04, the decision is very simple. Attempting anything else than using the provided fuse driver would be very technically challenging.

Comment: I have successfully run https://github.com/arter97/exfat-linux for a couple of weeks now and It seems stable. Pretty fast as well. Nevertheless I would prefer to avoid ppa repos and therefore I am trying to evaluate if the effort is worth it.

Comment: Based on your experience, you will be in the best position to answer this.